# Fire vanilla "change" events on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having trouble with jQuery not firing vanilla JavaScript events:

```
var jqSelect = $('select');
var vaSelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

vaSelect.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    console.log('Vanilla change: ', this.value);
}, false);

jqSelect.on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('jQuery change: ', $(this).val());
});

jqSelect.change(); // Same with jqSelect.trigger('change');
```

Output:

```
jQuery change:  0
```

JSFddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3qmyan6t/1 (thanks @arun-p-johny)

I want to use bootstrap-selectpicker (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) which fire jQuery events with a plugin listening to vanilla events.

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, is there a work-around?

**Edit:** My current work-around:

```
function changeEvent (e) {
    $(this).off('change.jqWorkAround');
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    $(this).on('change.jqWorkAround', changeEvent);
}
$('select').on('change.jqWorkAround', changeEvent);
```

This works pretty well if there is only vanilla listeners, if there is a jQuery listener, it is triggered twice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3qmyan6t/1/ ?

Comment: Yes, jQuery's trigger won't trigger events which jQuery is not aware of.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, that's the behaviour I'm talking about, I added your fiddle to my post (thanks).

Comment: @dfsq Is there any work-around? Or do I have to create my own?